# lprm / cancel both fail to cancel print jobs

Tags: linux, cups

I get 2 print jobs I would like to cancel :

```
Tux # lpq
photosmart_7200 is not ready
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
1st     unknown 190     unknown                         8192 bytes
2nd     unknown 191     unknown                         8192 bytes
```

Created by some non root localhost user (however member of lp & lpadmin groups) piping whatever ascii text to `lp`.)

However :

```
Tux # lprm -
lprm: Forbidden
Tux # cancel -a
cancel: cancel-job failed: Forbidden
```

No need to say that I get identical results via cups' browser interface, /var/log/cups_error.log says :

```
E [21/Sep/2022:08:41:10 +0200] [Client 9] Returning HTTP Interdit for Cancel-Job (ipp://localhost/jobs/190) from localhost
E [21/Sep/2022:08:47:00 +0200] [Client 14] Returning HTTP Interdit for Cancel-Job (ipp://localhost/jobs/191) from localhost
```

These jobs sit with their d-files and associated control files in /var/spool/cups :

```
Tux /var/spool/cups # ls -ails
…
878712 4 -rw------- 1 root lp   1032  6 juin   15:18 c00190
878713 4 -rw------- 1 root lp    940  6 juin   15:18 c00191
878714 4 -rw------- 1 root lp    832  6 juin   15:18 c00192
891424 4 -rw------- 1 root lp    954 17 sept.  22:42 c00193
891442 4 -rw------- 1 root lp    954 17 sept.  22:42 c00194
891435 4 -rw------- 1 root lp    954 17 sept.  22:42 c00195
878708 8 -rw-r----- 1 root lp   7288  6 juin   15:17 d00190-001
878711 8 -rw-r----- 1 root lp   7288  6 juin   15:18 d00191-001
885657 4 drwxrwx--T 2 root lp   4096 29 août  08:32 tmp
```

Running cups-2.4.2 (jobs most probably created running cups-2.3.3) under linux-5.4

So why can't these commands actually cancel the jobs, how can I politely (avoiding rm-ing them in the spool directory) cancel these jobs.
Additionally, can it be explained how comes the owner of these jobs are reported "*unknown*" by `lpq` since strings-ing the control files shows the valid user name ?

Comment: You might try `cupsctl --user-cancel-any` to update `cupsd.conf` to allow anyone to cancel a job.

Comment: @meuh : Thank you for the tip, however, as root, firing *cupsctl --user-cancel-any* results in *cupsctl: Forbidden*. Hmmm… might indicate a much wider problem with cups than only with the removal of two tasks ?

Comment: The Forbidden is probably from opening Unix domain socket `/var/run/cups/cups.sock`. Check permissions down to it. Perhaps the cupsd process is dead? Try `sudo systemctl status cups.socket cups`

Comment: Thank you a lot @meuh ! Your comment strongly invited me to dig into cups config files and I managed to find the solution !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, @meuh 's comment pointing to a wider problem, I investigated a little more in the cups config files and in particular `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` in which a policy is defined regarding job cancellation :

```
<Limit … Cancel-Jobs…>
    AuthType Default
    Require @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
</Limit>
```

Then looked for the definition of @SYSTEM which can be found in /etc/cups/cups-files.conf :

```
# Administrator user group, used to match @SYSTEM in cupsd.conf policy rules...
# This cannot contain the Group value for security reasons...
SystemGroup lpadmin
```

**The SystemGroup appears by default reduced to the lpadmin group !**

Since I had been running cancel commands as root and root group is not listed in the SystemGroup list and root user is not member of the lpadmin group… The forbidden answers I was facing were nothing but : logical.

Solved the problem by adding root user to the lpadmin group.

lpq is additionally now verbose regarding owner's user names.